# How does one read aloud a birth year with no death year? Eg: John Smith (1994 – )

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, style-manuals

It is common to notate someone's lifespan using the syntax `[year of birth] – [year of death]`. When the subject is still living, you simply omit the death year, such as `1994 –`.

When reading this aloud, is there a standard way to pronounce the unknown death year?

My hope would be that one is prescribed in a radio broadcast audio style guide, but I cannot locate any.

Comment: "Born 1994"....

Comment: These should be answers, not comments! Especially if you can find some audio styleguide recommending this approach.

Comment: That would require work.  "Work!!!"  Settle down, Maynard.

Answer (score 2):

*Obligatory "I am not a radio broadcaster" (but I am a native American English speaker)*

In all cases, when describing human life spans, I've read and heard this phrase read as:

> **"Nineteen-ninety-four to present"** (or "the present" or "the present day").

Other common options include:

> "Born in 1994, currently living"

or

> "Born in 1994, not yet deceased"

I would go with the option in bold if I were reading something aloud. Another really common option is simply not to say anything about the death year, implicitly stating that a death has not occurred.